# MySQL : reference a column from another column

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to add a dictionary funtion to my program using MySQL.

It would have 3 tables: `products`, `languages` and `product_dictionary`

The user would choose a product and a language and the corresponding product name would be found in the product_dictionary.

If the `products` table is:

```
products_id | product_name
1           | chocolate
2           | flour
```

and the `languages` table is:

```
languages_id | language_name
1            | english
2            | french
3            | german
```

I have two `product_dictionary` table ideas but I am not sure which is the best.

```
products_id | languages_id | translation
1           | 1            | chocolate
1           | 2            | chocolat
1           | 3            | Schokolade
2           | 1            | flour
2           | 2            | farine
```

Where the `product_id` and `language_id` create a compound primary key to find the translation;

or

```
products_id | english   | french   | german
1           | chocolate | chocolat | Schokolade
2           | flour     | Farine   | Mehl
```

Where the value of the `language_name` column from the `languages` table is the column name in the `product_dictionary` table and the `product_id` also being the primary key for the `product_dictionary` table.

Could someone give me there insight?
Thank you.

Comment: the first version of product_dictionary is better because it's more extensible - you can add more languages without altering the database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend the first option for a few reasons:

1. new languages may need to be added, and with option 2 that would require you to change the table strucutre, while with option 1 you'd only need to insert a new row
2. with option 1 the query you'd have to use in your code can have two parameters in its `where` clause, while with option two you'd have to build a different `select` for each language

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have the following database schema :

products

```
id_product |
1          |  
2          |  
3          |
```

languages  (same as you)

```
languages_id | language_name
1            | english
2            | french
3            | german
```

product_dictionary (the first one)

```
products_id | languages_id | translation
1           | 1            | chocolate
1           | 2            | chocolat
1           | 3            | Schokolade
2           | 1            | flour
2           | 2            | farine
```

You can add a PRIMARY_KEY on (products_id, languages_id) in product_dictionary.

This is generaly not a good idea to use a column for each language as it's not easy to maintain, if you add 100+ more languages for example.